# Is it possible to change the URL of custom post types to hide the post type slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I would like to turn /{custom-post-type}/{post-name} to /{post-name}, is this possible?

If this is not possible, can I change the labels/terminology in Pages or Posts so that they could be called "Clients" or "Projects" etc?

Answer (score 10):

You need to use option `'rewrite'` in your custom post type registration.

E.g.
`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),`

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#URLs_of_Namespaced_Custom_Post_Types_Identifiers)

> When you namespace a URL and still want to use a "clean" URL
>   structure, you need to add the "**rewrite**" element to the array. For
>   example, assuming the "ACME Widgets" example from above:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
> function create_post_type() {
>   register_post_type( 'acme_product',
>       array(
>           'labels' => array(
>               'name' => __( 'Products' ),
>               'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
>           ),
>           'public' => true,
>           'has_archive' => true,
>           'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products')
>       )
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> The above will result in a URL like
>   http:/example.com/products/%product_name% (see description of
>   %product_name% above.) Note that we used a plural form here which is a
>   format that some people prefer because it implies a more logical URL
>   for a page that embeds a list of products, i.e.
>   http:/example.com/products/.
>
> Also note using a generic name like "products" here can potentially
>   conflict with other plugins or themes that use the same name but most
>   people would dislike longer and more obscure URLs like
>   http:/example.com/acme_products/foobrozinator and resolving the URL
>   conflict between two plugins is easier simply because the URL
>   structure is not stored persistently in each post record in the
>   database in the same way custom post type names are stored.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I want the posts to have clean URLs but I do not want to have a post-type slug (the method you have quoted from the codex).

Comment: Thank you - worked for me!

Answer (score 8):

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false)
```

This will get the url correctly formed for you, but it will 404 unless you handle it in your theme.

Comment: True about 404, but as @Subhankar Adhikary mentions, resaving permalinks fixes it

Answer (score 4):

I just changed a slug for a custom post type (in this case, I changed it from `"best-practices"` to `"bestpractices"`). I had copied some code that had a blank slug, like so:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),
```

Since it was originally left blank, Wordpress was just using the name of the custom post type (`"best-practices"`) as the slug. I changed my line of code to

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'bestpractices'),
```

I just wanted to note here that you'll need to reset your permalinks to get the change to take effect, if you're changing slugs on pre-existing custom post types.

Comment: THANK YOU! I just spent an hour trying to figure out why my permalinks weren't updating. I didn't realize you'd need to go into the admin and "Save" your permalink structure again.

Answer (score 1):

yes, we can change the slug. Please follow the steps:

Step 1: Change the slug name from the option "rewrite". (located at Theme Functions (functions.php))

'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products')

Step 2: Reset the permanent link. Otherwise, it will give 404 error.
1> goto wp dashboard.
2> Setting --> Permalinks

Under the common setting section---
1st change it to plain and save it. 
After that, again change the setting as your preferred format.

Comment: It's enough to just click the save button in the permalinks section, I think no changes need to be done.